# Creating a list box in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that will include a list box. To make sure I've got my head wrapped around the concepts needed, I've looked up a tutorial on TechNet and tried to duplicate the code provided.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730949.aspx

If I'm following the walkthrough and script properly, it appears that the script is intended to present a dialog box and then output the selected item to the CLI. I've duplicated the dialog box, but I can't get it to write the selection to the CLI. I even modified the last line to explicitly call Write-Output to show the value of $x.

Everything about this script appears to work as intended, except for actually writing out any value for $x. Since `echo "$x"` is perhaps the simplest line in all that code, I can only presume the problem is actually with getting data *written* to $x instead.

Below is cut-and-paste from my PowerShell ISE window, which in turn was cut-and-paste from the aforementioned TechNet article:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Select a Computer"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please select a computer:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$objListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objListBox.Height = 80

[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-001")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-002")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-003")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-004")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-005")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-006")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-007")

$objForm.Controls.Add($objListBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

echo "$x"
```

When the above didn't work as expected, I decided to go step-by-step with the tutorial and re-write the script myself. I modified it a bit to better suit my organizational preferences and to add annotations along the way. However, now even the dialog itself is broken.

```
# Load Windows Forms & Drawing classes.
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

# Create base form.
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Text = "Select a Computer"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

# Configure keyboard intercepts for ESC & ENTER.
$objForm.KeyPreview = $true
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter")
    {
        $x = $objListBox.SelectedItem
        $objForm.Close()
    }
})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape")
    {
        $objForm.Close()
    }
})

# Create OK button.
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({
    $x = $objListBox.SelectedItem
    $objForm.Close()
})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

# Create Cancel button.
$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({
    $objForm.Close()
})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

# Add form prompt text.
$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20)
$objLabel.Text = "Please select a computer:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel)

# Add list box.
$objListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$objListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40)
$objListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$objListBox.Height = 80

# Populate list.
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Option1")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Option2")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Option3")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Option4")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Option5")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Option6")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Option7")

# Force list box to display on top of other windows.
$objForm.TopMost = $true

# Display list box.
$objForm.Add_Shown({
    $objForm.Activate()
})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

# Show result.
$x
```

The second code block results in this:

[image: Broken list box]

What am I doing wrong, here?

Note: I'm running PowerShell 3.0 on Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the OK button click handler to this:

```
$OKButton.Add_Click({$global:x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()})
```

Note the use of the `global:` scope specifier for the `$x` variable.  PowerShell uses dynamic scoping and employs a "copy-on-write" approach to variables.  That is, assuming $x is defined in the global scope, modifying `$x` in a function would only modify a local copy of the variable. If your intent is to modify the global value of $x you must use the global specifier e.g. `$global:x = ...`.

Comment: This sounds like it might reach outside the scope of the script. How can I use $x outside of that function while keeping it contained within the script? Also, what did I do that broke the dialog display in the second script?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out the first part of my comment-question. I changed `$x` to `$script:x` and that seems to have worked. Still, what's wrong in my second script?

Comment: Nevermind. Found it. I was missing `$objForm.Controls.Add($objListBox)`.

Comment: Last question: Since this script originated from a TechNet article, and there are similar scripts in the same series which define `$x` in a similar fashion, it would seem that this *should* have worked. Has something changed in PowerShell (e.g.: From 1.0 to 2.0, or to 3.0) that invalidated the script as it was originally written?

Comment: The original code worked in 1.0 and 2.0.  It breaks starting with 3.0.  If you look at the WMF 3.0 Release Notes there is a documented breaking change called `"Script blocks executed as delegates run in their own scope"` that describes the change.

Comment: Thanks. I take it that the explicit scope definition is backward-compatible with 2.0 and 1.0?

Comment: Yes, it is backwards compatible.

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to get the functionality of a list box is to use `Out-GridView`. For example:

```
'one','two','three','four' | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single
```

The user can select an item, and it will be returned in the pipeline.

You can also use `-OutputMode Multiple` for multi-selection.

Another example:

```
get-process | Out-GridView -OutputMode Multiple
```

[image]

This returns the selected object:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    396      24     5008       8964   113     8,88   3156 AuthManSvr
```